# Static/Fixed Sidebar and Fluid Content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have three DIVs, one is the header at the top which should be fixed (should not scroll), width 100%, height 50px; another is a sidebar to the left which needs to be 100% of browser's height, fixed width of 200px and another DIV for the main content to the right which will be fluid in width, that is 100% of the remaining width (total minus 200px).

Content in the main content DIV should scroll vertical as content grows, but the sidebar to the left and header DIV should remain as it is. YouTube's home page is the perfect example what I want to achieve. I tried all position types and widths, but no success. HTML is like this:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main-content"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Basic CSS code I am trying is:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
}
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    left: 220px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px; /*This could be anything, content should scroll vertical*/
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple css code :

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
#parent {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Example :
http://jsfiddle.net/rp4ss12b/

Your *top bar* and *side bar* need to be `position: fixed;`. Then your *main content* need to have a `margin-top` (in order not to be hidden by the top bar) and a `margin-left` (in order not to be hidden by the side bar).

Comment: Ohh, you didn't use any height 100%, instead the position zeroes. This is perfect, I made the top: 50px in #sidebar so that the sidebar is below the header.

Comment: I do not like to use width 100% or height 100% because it limits you on adding paddings and borders.

Comment: How would you handle this on small-screen devices where the sidebar is supposed to be hidden?

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:999;
}
#parent {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#sidebar {
    padding-top:50px; /* padding-top must be the same as header height */
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: blue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:99;
}
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:200px; /* padding-left must be the same as sidebar width */
    height: 300px; /* This could be anything, content should scroll vertical */
    background: green;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-top: 50px; /* padding-top must be the same as header height */
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is perfect for Chrome, but in IE8 the content is scrolling horizontally 200px more towards the right.

Comment: @forthaction Its working fine for me on IE8 doc mode, try that for full screen demo - http://jsfiddle.net/x548z89j/show/

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet, You can do this by using pure css as shown below or you can use display:inline-block or float elements but you need to set the width of right div using javascript.

```css
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
#header{position:fixed;height:50px;width:100%;background:#000;top:0;left:0;}
#parent{background:red;width:100%;height:100%;display:table;border-collapse:collapse;}
#parent div{display:table-cell;padding-top:50px;}
#sidebar{width:200px;background:#444;color:#fff;}
#main-content{background:#ccc;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="sidebar">sadds</div>
    <div id="main-content">dshajkashljk</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Header is overlapping the sidebar and main-content. And in IE8, main-content's content is showing in sidebar.

Comment: Can you check it now and make sure whether it is working fine. Currently I am on mac.