# Styling for fixed side bar in html page

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML code for what I want:

**HTML**

```
<div id="top-bar"><nav>...</nav></div>
<div id="page-area">
    <div id="side-bar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

The "top-bar" has a fixed height of 60px for all screens. I want the rest of the heights to be set correctly to make it responsive. How can I make the "side-bar" occupy the entire height of the page leaving 60px at the top for the nav?

Comment: pls share the layout...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static/Fixed Sidebar and Fluid Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945202/static-fixed-sidebar-and-fluid-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS3 you can specify `calc` for your rule values.

So assuming there's nothing else on your page, you could do something like:

```
#page-area {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add

```
body {padding-top:60px}
```

Comment: why downvote? with a fixed bar, if body hasn't padding, the content goes behind the bar.

Comment: I don't know why this has been down voted, I haven't tried this as @ne1410s 's solution worked perfectly for me. But, I guess this one will have padding-top.

Comment: I expect it has been down-voted due to lack of explanation.  SO is not only for assistance, but for teaching.   Giving a reason why the OP's details did not work, and why yours may, adds value to the community.

Comment: excuse me, @AnthonyHorne, in the original question there isn't a request to fix a problem. 
Maybe my answer is incomplete but i think a fully explantion on how padding works wasn't necessary in this case.

Comment: @user3083618 I hear you, but the fact that the user is asking this question means that his knowledge on padding / styling is not complete.  I didn't vote you down, but I surmise it is due to it being "marked as poor quality answer" - incomplete - as you said.